# remote ssh and graphic program resume

Tags: ssh, console, remote-server

I have an ssh server with an ubuntu distro installed.

I can connect via ssh to this server and run program with graphical interface (with X11 forwarding).

My question is:

there is a way to open, from a remote consolle, a graphical application that
is running on the ssh server?!

(obviously the user that has launched the application on the server, is the same
that is connected via ssh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do that with [vnc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers)

Comment: Thanks, this may be a good solution. But what i'm looking for is something like 'screen' command,  but for GUI.

Comment: vnc will do that. You ssh to the remote machine, start a vncserver and then connect to it with a vnc client (think start a screen session). You can then start a program with a GUI. From there, you can kill your client and close the connection (like detaching from the screen session). Later, you can reconnect to that same vncserver and recover the GUI windows the way it was when you left it (like screen -r).